# YouTube Java API: Get available video resolutions

Tags: java, youtube-api, gdata-api

I am building a simple Java application. Basically, I am searching a keyword on YouTube Data API and getting the video list. Each video has description, author, duration and thumbnail. Everything is working great. Now, I would like to eliminate 240p videos but couldn't find proper solution. Apparently, video entry feed doesn't have that information.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can only filter by the HD parameter:

http://apiblog.youtube.com/2011/10/more-ways-to-find-what-youre-looking.html

hd - This one lets you request videos that have high-resolution versions available. If you specify hd (no value is needed), all the videos in your search results will be available for playback in at least 720p, and higher resolutions, like 1080p, might be available, too. If you leave the parameter out, then search results won't be filtered at all based on resolution. The  element corresponds to this search parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already filtered content by hd parameter. But in this case, I lose 480p and 360p videos. Any other suggestion?

Comment: It's not possible to filter out videos that are only available in 240p. Matias's answer describes the only type of filtering we do support.

Comment: Thanks @JeffPosnick. It is good to hear that from a member of YouTube API team.